# Is it possible to print from PowerDOS/DosPad to iOS print dialogue?

Tags: printing, ios

I recently installed [PowerDOS/DosPad](https://litchie.com/dospad) — which is effectively [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com) on iOS — onto my iPad mini 1. I use it for [Dale Harris’s POS](http://keyhut.com/pos.htm).

It works great, the only problem is I just can’t seem to figure out how to print to the iOS 9 print dialogue or any sort of print. I have a Bluetooth receipt printer that I would like to use.

Thank you to anyone who has any advice on how to make this possible.

Comment: https://github.com/litchie/dospad/issues may be the better place to get answers actually.